# Телеграм бот на C# отвечает одному в зависимости от другого пользователя

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, visual-studio, telegram

У меня есть такая проблема
Есть бот, который принимает картинки и текст поочерёдно
То есть, если ему отправить картинку, он попросит отправить текст и наоборот, если ему отправить сначала картинку, а когда попросит текст, то он ответит что нужно следовать инструкциям
Проблема в том, что допустим пользователь 1 отправляет боту картинку и бот пишет ему про то, что теперь нужно отправить текст, но если в этот момент пользователь 2 тоже отправит картинку, то он напишет пользователю 2, что нужно следовать инструкциям, а по сути должен запросить отправить текст. Получается так, что пользователи бота как-то связаны, а мне нужно чтобы он для всех работал отдельно

Comment: Вы сейчас говорите о логике, о коде, который нам не показываете, вам самим-то абстракция поможет, или всеж хотите узнать где именно вы накосячили? Ну, если абстракция поможет, ок, реализуйте так называемую "машину состояния", ну и при переходе на следующее состояние записывайте его и id пользователя, например, в базу. Когда в следующий раз напишет вам, ищете в базе текущее состояние и продолжаете диалог с этого места. Ну а если диалога нет условно час, удаляете запись из базы (для такого отлично кстати подходит Redis), что сбросит диалог до стартового состояния.

Comment: абстракция помогла, спасибо!